# How to run multiple threads within a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, image-processing

I'm using google translator because my English is terrible.
I want to know if I can have multiple threads within a for loop with several repetitions.
I have a folder with multiple images and it takes a long time for the program to process them one by one, so I want to have a parallel image processing for each individual image.

Code sample:

```
for element in listSample:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=function, arg=element)
    thread.start()
```

I want each thread to handle a thread independently.

Comment: If you're going to be doing some actual processing within Python (as opposed to calling external processes), threads won't help you due to the [dreaded GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). What you're looking for is the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module, in particular [Using a pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) can work well for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [IO-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) tasks here, such as access to storage and retrieving images, you can benefit from incorporating [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) features, in particular the [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) module.
Meanwhile, as was mentioned, the actual processing (the [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) part of the program) may benefit from using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module, which overcomes limitations of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).
For how to cooperate `multiprocessing` and `asycnio`, check this [great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=10m30s&v=0kXaLh8Fz3k&feature=youtu.be) by [John Reese](https://jreese.sh/)!
Good luck!